# Using hidden files with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, ms-access-2016

My MS Access database has to use some files but if I hide them, it throws Error 75 ("Path/File access error").

How can I specify in the part of the code where I write the path to these files, that they are hidden?

Comment: Hi. I've find [this solution for Excel](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-13726.html) that might be helpful to you, if you adapt it to Access

Comment: I'll give a look, thanks!